# Attaching cable company service wire to side of house

Tags: siding, coaxial-cable, cable-management

Currently, the various cable company wires that are attached to the side of my house are a mess, and I'm looking to clean them up before our house is painted in the near future. One of them is attached to the siding with some sort of tensioning system, and the others are zip-tied to the first line and the service mast. The one that is attached with tension is being removed and I would like to re-attach the remaining ones to something similar, but I've Googled without success as to what it is called. Is there another/better way to attach the cables that will remain to the house? Or can someone tell me what the circled things are called so I find and buy a new one?

[image]

Comment: I think that if you cut the one you've identified, the rest of the bundle will fall until it's supported by that zip tie lower down on the conduit clamp. That zip tie may not take the strain of all those cables falling, and probably won't last very long with all the weight of them on it, especially come the next windy day when they're bouncing around. Other than cutting off the piece of cable hanging down from your right-hand red circle, I'm not sure what cleaning up you could do, but I'm sure someone will have a suggestion for you.

Comment: Yeah, that ziptie is rather naughty anyway...

Comment: Are these all for services to you? At the entry point into your house, they should have a drip loop. So the slope of the wire at entry is downwards. You shouldn't remove that.

Answer (score 3):

The red point on the right is called a "P hook" and the red point on the left is a "drop clamp." Drop clamps are used to make sure the strain on the cable is parallel to the length of the cable and doesn't force the cable into a bent or kinked state.

Coaxial cables intended for aerial drops like this typically have a "messenger wire" that further reduces the strain; non-reinforced RG-6 coaxial has a maximum rating of 35lb pull force but some have up to 126lbs. Weight of coaxial is roughly 35lb per 1000 feet so short runs aren't a big deal without messenger wire support.

For your application, you can leave the P hook and replace the drop clamp unless you can reuse the existing one. I'd try to combine all of those coax drops into one cable if possible and split it further down the line (but I can't see what else they're connected to in this photo).

Note also that cables are supposed to be protected within 8' of grade, this typically means entering a conduit where it meets the house and runs down the wall inside conduit, so multiple cables can be contained in conduit and have a much neater look.

[Source - cable install primer](https://www.commscope.com/globalassets/digizuite/2422-drop-const-manual-co-107145.pdf)

On the other hand, your siding appears to be vinyl; is that what you're painting?

Comment: "cables are supposed to be protected within 8' of grade". Interesting... maybe I should give Comcast a call and have 'em put some conduit around mine, and all my neighbors, and everyone else in town's... Not saying you're wrong, just saying the certainly don't enforce it 'round here.

Comment: Yes, the vinyl siding is what is being painted. The line currently in the drop clamp is being removed back to the pole, it's not currently connected to anything. The other 2 coax drops are for the two local cable ISP options, I'm leaving both. I just wanted them attached better than crudely zip-tied to things.

I've found coax drop clamps online and will purchase one. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: @FreeMan I'm"lucky" to live in an area where they bury cables instead of running overhead, and after a lot of run-ins with fence post holes they're finally burying in conduit all the way to the house and sealing the conduit at the home end.

Comment: Instead of removing the cable that has a messenger wire and is correctly tied to your house, why don't you have one of the cable companies swap their service onto it, and remove one of the ones hanging from it?

Comment: @jay613 It's an old DSL line I believe, I don't think it's coax.

Comment: That “drop clamp” or wedge clamp is multiple pieces. The center piece has a cable that attaches to the anchor point the “p” hook or eye lag. The messenger wire goes in a groove and the outside piece is slipped over the center and slid back the tension from the messenger locks them in place. I would not remove any support as it looks like multiple cables are on that clamp.